# PDFKit unable to write a file to stream

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to get the following to work, I have a GET REST request hitting an endpoint which runs `receipt`. I get no errors from the below but when I check the returned blob but nothing to show the text I added is present.

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

// User Receipt
exports.receipt = function(req, res) {
    var guid = req.params.guid;
    console.log(guid);

    var doc = new PDFDocument();
    var stream = doc.pipe( res );

    doc.moveTo(300, 75)
       .lineTo(373, 301)
       .lineTo(181, 161)
       .lineTo(419, 161)
       .lineTo(227, 301)
       .fill('red', 'even-odd');  

    var loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in...';  

    doc.y = 320;
    doc.fillColor('black')
    doc.text(loremIpsum, {
       paragraphGap: 10,
       indent: 20,
       align: 'justify',
       columns: 2
    });  

    doc.end();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

    stream.on('finish', function() {
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
};
```

Client side I have the following code:

```
var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
$window.open(fileURL);
```

But the page returns with `Failed to load PDF document`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the headers before you pipe. Also, you should only be piping to `res` once.

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

// User Receipt
exports.receipt = function(req, res) {
    var guid = req.params.guid;
    console.log(guid);

    var doc = new PDFDocument();

    doc.moveTo(300, 75)
       .lineTo(373, 301)
       .lineTo(181, 161)
       .lineTo(419, 161)
       .lineTo(227, 301)
       .fill('red', 'even-odd');  

    var loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in...';  

    doc.y = 320;
    doc.fillColor('black')
    doc.text(loremIpsum, {
       paragraphGap: 10,
       indent: 20,
       align: 'justify',
       columns: 2
    });
    doc.end();

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    return doc.pipe(res);
};
```

Comment: My PDF file which opens fine and with no errors but it now just says `[object object]`